# Need help on updating mysql database from wpf datagrid use Two-Way binding using submit command

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

basically i'm new in C# and WPF,

i have a WPF DataGrid that bind with DataTable

here the XAML for DataGrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" 
           Margin="10,99,0,56" Name="dataGrid1" 
           SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" Width="1044">  
</DataGrid>
```

here the public method from another class to load MySQL data into DataTable

```
public DataTable dtQueries(string userQuery, string cnString = null)
{
    //##Open the connection
    if (cnString == null)
    {
        this.open_connection("localConnectionString");
    }
    else
    {
        this.open_connection(cnString);
    }

    //##Create Command
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(userQuery, mysqlConn);

    //##Create a data reader and Execute the command

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(table);

    return table;
}
```

and here the code to bind DataTable into DataGrid

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string qGetDM = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

dataGrid1.BeginInit();

ds.Tables.Add(dboperation.dtQueries(qGetDM, "clientLegacyDM"));
dataGrid1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];

dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
dataGrid1.EndInit();
```

i have one command button as a SubmitButton to update MySQL database based on what user change in DataGrid..

anyone have suggestion how to do this?

thx, i really really appreciate any help :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own problem, this solution might not the best solution, but at least its work for me.

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" 

        Margin="10,99,0,56" Name="dataGrid1" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" 
        Width="1044" 
</DataGrid>
```

next, I recreate the

> public method from another class to load MySQL data into DataTable

for now i'm using `DataSet` here is the method, let name this class `MySQLOp`

```
public MySqlDataAdapter mysqlDA; //Member variable of class "MySQLOp"
public DataSet mysqlDS; //Member variable of class "MySQLOp"

//public method to return user query as a DataSet
public DataSet dsQueries(string userQuery, string cnString = null)
{
    //##Open the connection
    if (cnString == null)
    {
        this.open_connection("localConnectionString");
    }
    else
    {
        this.open_connection(cnString);
    }

    //##Create Command
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(userQuery, mysqlConn);
    mysqlDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    mysqlDS = new DataSet();

    mysqlDA.Fill(mysqlDS);

    return mysqlDS;

}
```

on wpf window lets named it "FormCRUD", I create one `commandbutton` to load the data, here is the code:

```
MySQLOp dboperation;
public yourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dboperation = new MySQL();
}

private void btnClLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string tablename = "your_table_name";
    qGetDM = "SELECT * FROM " + tablename;

    //#### Bind the DataSet to the GridView ####
    dataGrid1.BeginInit();

    //## Get Clien Data and return as DataSet
    dboperation.dsQueries(qGetDM, "clientLegacyDM");

    //## Set DataGrid ItemSource
    dataGrid1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding
    {
        Source = dboperation.mysqlDS.Tables[0]
    });
    dataGrid1.Items.Refresh();
    dataGrid1.EndInit();

}
```

on the `MySQLOp class`, I create another method to save `DataSet` to save back to MySQL DB, here is the method:

```
public DataSet CreateCommandAndUpdate()
{            
    MySqlCommandBuilder myBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mysqlDA);
    mysqlDA.Update(mysqlDS);
    return mysqlDS;
}
```

finally, i add another `commandbutton` in `FormCRUD` to as a `SubmitUpdate`, to submit data change back to database that call `CreateCommandAndUpdate()` method, heres the code

```
private void btnClUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dboperation.CreateCommandAndUpdate();
}
```

for me this just a temporary solution, I'm still looking for best and elegant solution.
Maybe you can give me another solution.